# Dynamic DIV box height with center position of the child DIV

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build the html with css styling schematically presented in the picture below: 
[image]

I manage to position the inner div with the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<div style="background-color: yellow; width: 100px; height: 100px; 
position: relative;">
    <div style="background-color: gray;  position: absolute; 
    top: 8px; left: 8px; right: 8px; bottom: 8px"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but the problem is that it stops to work if I want the height of outer div to be dynamic. Removing height value hides outer div.

How that could be achieved under all conditions?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? To vertically center the inner DIV no matter the height of the outer DIV?

Comment: With no content inside the outer div it will collapse on itself. Do you have any content inside the inner div?

Comment: yes the inner div has content inside

Comment: @Ionut G. Stan, I want to position the inner div inside outer one with fixed offset 'x'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is width 'W' known? Ah, it is somewhat irrelevant...

OK, you need to do something like this (assuming you position the outer div where you want it). :

```
<div style="float:left; background-color:yellow; width:100px;">
     <div style="background-color:gray; margin:8px;">You need enough content here to push the width out far enough...</div>
</div>
```

You may need to place the outside div in a further outside div to get the positioning correct, but the outside div must have a the float variable (left or right - it doesn't matter).

You can add borders and padding etc to these divs to suit. The key to the whole process is the float value existing in the outer div.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure where you're going with this. But it seems you want to just have padding around the inner div?

```
<div style="background-color: yellow; width: 100px; 
            position: relative; padding: 8px">
<div style="background-color: gray;">Hello</div>
```

This way, the content of the inner div will alter the height of the outer div...

Comment: In this case, you can has only 1 dynamic position div.

Comment: This solution is ok, but padding extends the width of the div so in order to have 100px width, the one should put width:84px; padding: 8px.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only absolute position object[s] in Relative position object, you must fix height value of Relative position object.

Hint. You can change height value via javascript or define min-height(CSS 2+) property of relative position object.